# Adding Spring Boot Keycloak configuration of HTTP requests

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

Currently in my **SecurityConfig.java** class file where I define my **KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** I want to define so that every GET request can be done by two different roles. But only one role can do the other types of HTTP requests (POST, PUT, PATCH etc). How can this be achieved in my code below:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).hasAnyRole("user", "admin")
        .anyRequest().hasRole("admin");
}
```

What happens is that when trying to do POST request I get access denied 403. GET requests works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should disable csrf on your configure method :

```
 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` nor anything else from Keycloak libs for Spring, [it is deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187).

Instead, you can follow [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers) which proposes two solutions based on:

- `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` which requires [quite some Java conf](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken)
- `spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server` which enables to [configure most of security from properties](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication) (way simpler than preceding)

All tutorials linked here show how to map Keycloak roles to spring-security authorities (and will keep CSRF protection enabled, even for stateless resource-servers).